# Is it true that: $|a_{n+1} - L| < |a_{n} - L| \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \implies \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = L ?$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $a_{n}$ is a sequence and $|a_{n+1} - L| < |a_{n} - L|,  \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $, then clearly the sequence $s_{n} = |a_{n} - L|$ converges (it's decreasing and bounded by $0$).
Does it converge to $0$ (which would imply that $a_{n}$ converges to $L$)?
If it does not hold, does someone have a counterexample?

Comment: Suppose $a_n = 1/2 + 1/n.$ Then $|a_{n+1}-0 | \le |a_n-0|.$ Does $a_n \to 0$?

Comment: There is hardly anything to add to all the good answers and comments already posted. The main point is that your condition is enough to guarantee that the sequence $|a_n -L|$ converges to a number, but this number need not be 0. Only if it is 0 we have $a_n \to L$, but in many cases, as shown below, it will not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n=n/(n+1)$.  This is a monotonically increasing sequence.  So, $|a_n-2|>|a_{n+1}-2|$ for all $n$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n-2|\ne 0$.  This is because $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=1$.

Comment: The condition states that: $|a_{n+1}-L| < |a_n-L|$, yours is reversed.

Comment: Ah yes.  My reversed statement is actually incorrect. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Non-monotone example (in fact the sequence does not converge):

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)\cdot(-1)^n\ \ \ \ \not\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\ n\to\infty\ \atop\ }0$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$